# C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook launch from Windows Service

Tags: c#, outlook, windows-services

I'm using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` to do the following:-

1. Read an Outlook folder called 'Pending'
2. Get the attachment from all emails under 'Pending' folder
3. Save the attachment to hard disk folder
4. Read the attachment from the saved file and upload to our data base

All the above points are working perfectly fine if I run my C# console application manually.
It also works sometimes when I launch the console application from Windows Service. But some times not. 
I read somewhere in Stack that `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` is not designed for Windows Services.

What is the best method (quick and fast to develop) to all the above task from Windows Service?

Comment: you need to set you window service account to `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem` or `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User` it will ask user name and password while installation

Comment: @DarshanPatel that won't work.  See answer below

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best method (quick and fast to develop) to all the above task **from Windows Service**?

Short answer - *you can't.*

COM Automation servers such as the ones from Microsoft Office are GUI-based and therefore require a *message pump*.   When you consider that Windows Services typically run *prior* to a user logging in, it's not possible to launch a process that attempts to show a GUI.   It would simply lock-up.

One could argue that you could always wait until the user logs into Windows but then it sort of defeats the purpose of windows services - that user login is not necessary.   Plus if Windows were to reboot your app would not run until the user logs in again.

Comment: Well I mean you [caaaan pump messages in a service](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/241133/detecting-a-wm-timechange-event-in-a-net-windows-service) but `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` is going to be a disaster in a non-interactive environment - message pump or not. [*Office applications assume that they are being run under an interactive desktop ... This fact alone makes running Office Applications from a server-side environment risky and unsupported.*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)

Comment: If OP's use of *Outlook* here is synonymous with *Exchange Server* then there's managed APIs that won't require interactivity: https://github.com/officedev/ews-managed-api

Comment: @ta.speot.is Agreed.  I've seen people put a message pump into a console app but why would you?  Same goes for a service.  No amount of message pumping is going to help if there is no interactive Winstation present.

Comment: @ta.speot.is EWS?  All that is are managed wrappers around a REST API to a remote server.  Emphasis on _server_

Comment: @MickyD At least for testing, if I move the code from Console application to GUI and auto click the button to do the above, will it work?

Comment: @MickyD I'm also planning to re write my code to directly get the emails from mail server. As I am new to this, will it take time ? Please provide some keyword, so that I can search and find information. Also, if it will work from GUI (called from windows service), why it does not work from console app (just curious to know),

Comment: @Rauf _"if it will work from GUI (called **from** windows service)"_ - like I said that won't work

Comment: Yes EWS. If Outlook is connecting to an Exchange Server mailbox then just ... cut out the middleman ... and go straight to Exchange Server.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Thank you very much. Using EWS is easy or hard? Can I do within 6 hours?

Comment: @MickyD Hope it is better to use GUI app with a timer to poll the Outlook folder and ensure both Outlook and GUI app is running. Also I will try to use EWS ( but hope it will take time)